# AMPscript ContentAreaByName Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%=[IF @country == IT then]=%% 

%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\IT")=%%
```

Just i have removed the flower brackets just try it will work out.

I'm trying to built a Content Box using *ContentAreaByName* function and *IF Statement*, but it doesn't work.
Please find below the code snippet:

```
%%[VAR @country
SET @country = Country
]%%


%%=[IF (@country) == IT then]=%% 
%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\IT")=%% 

%%=[END IF]=%%

%%=[IF (@country) == FR then]=%% 
%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\FR")=%% 

%%=[END IF]=%%
```

When I try to preview in ET I receive this error:

**Unable to generate preview**

> A scripting error has occurred. The function call uses an unrecognized
>   function name. Function Name: [IF Function Call: [IF (@country) == IT
>   then]

Could you point where am I doing wrong?
Thank you,
Giulia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some quotes in your `IF` statements.  Also, there's no space in `ENDIF`.

Here's how I usually do these types of conditionals:

```
%%[
VAR @country, @contentPath
SET @country = AttributeValue("Country") /* handles null values */

IF @country == "IT" then
  set @contentPath = "My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\IT"
elseif @country == "FR" then
  set @contentPath = "My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\FR"
else
  set @contentPath = "My Contents\3_content_test\test_HEADER\COUNTRY\DEFAULT"
endif

]%%
%%=ContentAreaByName(@contentPath)=%%
```